# Looking for \newcommand code for the following purpose

Tags: macros

Command name resumeAchv

Should look like the following

**Achievement name**: Achievement description (multiple lines,‎ more text   ‎ ‎ ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎‎*Year of achv*  should go into multiple lines, left aligned.)

I've gotten as far as

```
\newcommand{\resumeAchv}[3]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
\begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}[t]
{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{#1}:#2 & \textit{#3}
}
```

However, the document does not compile and the compiler says that the commands below the only occurrence of resumeAchv seem not to exist.

Any pointers or solutions?

Comment: as always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Note that that `\item` command seems very strange there. But since I do not known the context....

Comment: Do you close the `tabular` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tabularx}     

\newcommand{\resumeAchv}[3]{%
  \vspace{0.5mm}\item
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}Xr@{}}
    \textbf{#1}: #2 & \textit{#3} \\
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \resumeAchv{Achievement Name}{Achievement Description}{Year of Achievement}
  \resumeAchv{Another Achievement}{Another Description}{2022}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\linewidth`, rather than `0.98\textwidth`

Comment: Thanks for that. What does the ```{@{}Xr@{}}``` mean?

Comment: I also wanted some gap between the bullet point and the #1. I managed to do that by adding a space before the #1 within the {}, but the #2 starts from the left and right under the whitespace. How do I move it slightly to the right?

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\items}{
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\end{enumerate}
}

 
\newcommand{\resumeAchv}[3]{
\vspace{0.5mm} \items
\begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}[t]
{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{#1}:#2 & \textit{#3}
\end{tabular*}
}

\begin{document}
\resumeAchv{a}{b}{c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this definition of `\items` make any sense? Isn't this like hard coding a `1.`?

Comment: Why the `item` at all? Already in the OP's question the purpose of this macro was/is not clear.